# Can’t access unicode keys. Possibly, Javascript JSON parser bug?

Tags: javascript, json, unicode, key

I have a json string, that has Unicode key:

```
{"Текст":"Text"}
```

I can successfully `JSON.parse` it and then `JSON.stringify` – it will be the same.

I can’t access `Текст` key; it is undefined:

```
JSON.parse('{"Текст":"Text"}')["Текст"] // undefined
```

I can’t get keys by `Object.keys()`, it returns 0.

I tried to escape Unicode in string before parsing it, and even escape Unicode in brackets when trying to access a key, but it doesn’t help.

---

Page has

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Json string is returned by php’s `echo`. Php code has at the beginning

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

String by itself displays correctly.

---

Update

I changed content type to plain text to all script (can’t use pc and devtools, unfortunately), to see how the json string is `echo`. It is escaped:

```
...,"\u041d\u0430\u0447\u0430\u043b\u043e":"some value",...
```

Update 2

I changed escaped unicode to just unicode, but still facing the issues

Update 3

I think it is indeed a bug. As I wrote above, json object parsed from unicode string is absolutely valid. I can’t access it’s keys, but if I `stringify` it, it will return a valid string.

I thought: “what if to parse and then set key, that should be there?”. I did it – nothing is changed. And more – adding any key is not affecting a json object. When I stringify it, it returns an original string, without any changes.

Comment: Cannot reproduce, `JSON.parse('{"Текст":"Text"}')["Текст"]` works for me.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, indeed, me too. So what can be the problem

Comment: You'll only be able to push this logic so far it breaks code, but it works and only because the key is a string indentifier.

Comment: let e = JSON.parse('{"Текст":"Text"}');
console.log(e["Текст"]);

works?

Comment: I'd suggest debugging the code, and checking every part of it (look what the string is, look what the call to `JSON.parse` gives, etc). It's a bit weird, that `JSON.parse` gives a empty object, i'd have expected an exception, if the string was mangled.

Comment: @ASDFGerte, unfortunately, can’t access pc now. I updated question with new details

Comment: @blanknamefornow I updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since native `JSON` stuff doesn’t work, I’ve made my own solution to set/get json keys:

```
function JSONget(j, k)
{
var i = j.search('"'+k+'"');

if(i == -1)
return j;

i+=k.length;

while(j[i] != ':' && i < j.length)
i++;

i++;

if(j[i]=='"')
i++;

var buffer = [];

for(var a=0; i < j.length; i++, a++)
{
if((j[i]=='"'&&j[i-1]!='\\')||(j[i]==','&&j[i+1]=='"'))
    break;
    
buffer[a] = j[i];
}

return buffer.join('');
}


function JSONset(j, k, v)
{
var i = j.search('"'+k+'"');

if(i == -1)
return j;

i+=k.length;

while(j[i] != ':' && i < j.length)
i++;

i++;

if(j[i]=='"')
i++;

var buffer = [];

for(var a=0; i < j.length; i++, a++)
{
if((j[i]=='"'&&j[i-1]!='\\')||(j[i]==','&&j[i+1]=='"'))
    break;
    
buffer[a] = j[i];
}

var t = j.split('"'+k+'"');

t[1] = t[1].replace(buffer.join(''), v);

return t[0]+('"'+k+'"')+t[1];
}
```

Use

```
JSONget('{"Текст":"Text"}', "Текст") // Text
JSONset('{"Текст":"Text"}', "Текст", "Latin vs Cyrillic") // "Текст":"Latin vs Cyrillic"
```